# How to clear Laravel storage folder when migrate refresh with seed option

Tags: laravel, storage, database-migration, laravel-seeding

How to clear Laravel storage folder when migrate refresh?
I want to clear `storage/app/public` folder when running command `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`

what I have tried:
add `(new Filesystem)->deleteDirectory(storage_path('app/public/images'));` on `database/seeders/DatabaseSeeder.php` but not working, when I

Answer (score 1):

I'll share here some snippet, which you can put in your **database/seeders/DatabaseSeeder.php**, so it will do all the work. Just don't forget that you probably [by default](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/9.x/storage/app/public) will have **storage/app/public/.gitignore** file, which is not need to be deleted.
So here's a snippet to delete files & filders with the exceptions.

**NOTE**: run "**php artisan storage:link**" before running the seeder, to have access to the resources in storage disk.

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $fs = new Filesystem;

        // delete directories
        $except_folder_names = [
            // folder name (storage/app/public/<folder_name>)
        ];
        $folder_paths = $fs->directories(public_path('storage'));
        foreach ($folder_paths as $folder_path) {
            $folder_name = last(explode('/', $folder_path));
            if (!in_array($folder_name, $except_folder_names)) {
                $fs->deleteDirectory($folder_path);
            }
        }

        // delete files
        $except_file_names = [
            '.gitignore',
            // file name (storage/app/public/<file_name>)
        ];
        $file_paths = $fs->files(public_path('storage'));
        foreach ($file_paths as $file_path) {
            $file_name = last(explode('/', $file_path));
            if (!in_array($file_name, $except_file_names)) {
                $fs->delete($file_path);
            }
        }

        echo "Uploads successfully deleted!\n";
        
        // OTHER SEEDERS...
    }
}
```

With this you can delete all the stuff (files and folders recursively) from **storage/app/public**

In other case, if you want to just clean directories, but not delete them, you can use something like this instead:

```
$directory = public_path('storage/' . $folder_name);
$file->cleanDirectory($directory);
```